# create new column in pandas based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with column like this:

```
    column_1
0   0.75 / 1 / 1.25 
1   0.25 / 0 / -0.25 / 0
2   0 / -0.25 / 0 / -0.25 / 0
3   0 / -0.25 
4   0.5 / 0.25
5   0.25
```

each row is made of chain of consecutive numbers (movement between numbers by 0.25,
for example from 0 to 0.25 to 0.5, or from -1 to -1.25)
I need only rows where the same number don't occur 2 times (or more), example : 0.25 / 0 / 0.25 / 0 / 0.25 / 0 or 0.5 / 0.25 / 0.5
I don't need rows with only one number, for example 0.25

I want to create new column, and keep those who who meet this condition (same number don't occur 2 times (or more))

```
    column_1                     new_column
0   0.75 / 1 / 1.25              0.75 / 1 / 1.25 
1   0.25 / 0 / -0.25 / 0         NaN
2   0 / -0.25 / 0 / -0.25 / 0    NaN
3   0 / -0.25                    0 / -0.25 
4   0.5 / 0.25                   0.5 / 0.25
5   0.25                         NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative answer:

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'column_1': ['0.75 / 1 / 1.25','0.25 / 0 / -0.25 / 0','0 / -0.25 / 0 / -0.25 / 0',
                 '0 / -0.25', '0.5 / 0.25', 0.25, np.nan, 'NaN'
                ]
})
# To handle np.NaN's using .fillna()
df['column_1'] = df['column_1'].fillna('0')

# To handle cases where numeric values in column
df['column_1'] = df['column_1'].astype(str)

# Split string to list and compare
df['split'] = df['column_1'].apply(lambda x: [i.replace('-','') for i in x.split(' / ')])
df['new_column'] = df['split'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if len(set(x))==1 else
                                     x if len(set(x))==len(x) 
                                     else np.nan)
df = df.drop('split', axis=1) # drop column
```

Output

```
print(df)

                    column_1       new_column
0            0.75 / 1 / 1.25  [0.75, 1, 1.25]
1       0.25 / 0 / -0.25 / 0              NaN
2  0 / -0.25 / 0 / -0.25 / 0              NaN
3                  0 / -0.25        [0, 0.25]
4                 0.5 / 0.25      [0.5, 0.25]
5                       0.25              NaN
6                          0              NaN
7                        NaN              NaN
```

Comment: return an exception: "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'"

Comment: It may be due to numeric values in `column_1`. I have updated the code to first set the `column_1` as string.

Comment: I converted the column to string, but return a new column with NaN (all values are NaN)

Comment: (1) Could you confirm if the code in the answer above works on your side? Because it works fine on my computer. (2) It is difficult to diagnose the problem without seeing the entire data set. I would guess that the `column_1` could have a mix of different data types. Could you post samples of the data in `column_1` that are different from those posted in the question above? (3) I'm using Pandas version: 1.0.3; and Python: 3.7.4

Comment: the column_1 contains some NaN, It can be the cause ?

Comment: It could be possible. However, there could be other reasons as well. I have updated the code to handle `NaN`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way splitting those strings and exploding, then keeping only those where `Series.is_unique` is `True` and they have more than one element:

```
l = df.column_1.str.split(' / ')
m = (l.explode()
      .groupby(level=0, sort=False)
      .apply(lambda x: x.is_unique) 
       & (l.str.len()>1))
df['new_column'] = df.where(m)
```

---

```
print(df)

                    column_1        new_column
0           0.75 / 1 / 1.25   0.75 / 1 / 1.25 
1       0.25 / 0 / -0.25 / 0               NaN
2  0 / -0.25 / 0 / -0.25 / 0               NaN
3                 0 / -0.25         0 / -0.25 
4                 0.5 / 0.25        0.5 / 0.25
5                       0.25               NaN
```

Comment: it returns an exception : '''Series' object has no attribute 'explode'"

Answer (score 2):

Create a helper Series of lists of numbers using `split` and `strip`. Compare the length of the lists with their corresponding `set` and use boolean logic to create `new_column`:

```
s = df['column_1'].apply(lambda x: [x.strip() for x in x.split('/')])

df['new_column'] = df.loc[(s.str.len() == s.apply(set).str.len()) & (s.str.len() != 1), 'column_1']
```

[out]

```
                    column_1       new_column
0            0.75 / 1 / 1.25  0.75 / 1 / 1.25
1       0.25 / 0 / -0.25 / 0              NaN
2  0 / -0.25 / 0 / -0.25 / 0              NaN
3                  0 / -0.25        0 / -0.25
4                 0.5 / 0.25       0.5 / 0.25
5                       0.25              NaN
```

Comment: return an exception: "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'"